# Bicycle pedaling resistance on single speed e-bike

Tags: chain, repair, chainring, electric-bike

Recently, I've bought an ebike that is about 2 months old now, I've maybe gotten 100-150 miles off of it as a daily commuter. When I pedal, it would have a lot of opposing force or friction, and pedaling harder doesn't make a difference. I've kind of deduced that the issue was purely mechanical and the hub motor had nothing to do with it since when I turned the bike off, it would do the same thing.

So essentially what happens is, it alternates, 90% of the time it would be hard to pedal and the rest of the time it operates seemingly normal. I had taken my chain off the derailleur and the problem persists. I thought maybe lack of lubrication in that tube in the bottom axle bracket of the bike that connects the pedal crank arms?

Some more details about my bike, it is a single speed, hub motor bicycle. I disconnected my brake sensors to use a road bike handlebar so I'm not sure how this factors into it. Please, anyone give your suggestions or thoughts, and thank you.

**EDIT**

Bike has rim brakes, not disc brakes

Comment: What make bike is it? Was it like this before you disconnected the brake sensors?

Comment: The brake sensors I've worked on didn't fail in a way that would disable the motor (lucky as the attachment was flimsy and under stress from the brake cable once the barrel adjuster had been tightened, so they came detached quite soon). These could easily be different (following on from @DanK' s comment).

Comment: @DanK no it wasn't like this before. but this didn't happen immediately after either and I don't believe the problem has anything to do with any of the electronic components.

Comment: Sounds like the bottom bracket has gone south. Usually, they are a replaceable part, so it's fixable by any odd bike shop. But since the problem started after only 2 month and 240km, I guess that's very firmly within what's covered by the warranty.

Comment: @cmaster I believe you are correct. It seems to be the only plausible answer after thinking on it, darn..

Comment: Could you try and disconnect the motor wires from the controller (if this is somewhat easy to do) and see if the problem persists?

Comment: Have you checked if the brake is rubbing?